# How to change "oper" value in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, forms, parameters, jqgrid, edit

as you can see in jqgrid. There are some parameter that will be send to serverside during edit form data.

```
Problem_date:2011-05-04
Line:FA 09
Shift:A
Model:KD-S27JD
Serial_number:106X2431
DIC:MC
Def_class:A
Symptom:Page 4 until 6 of Instruction Book missing printing
Cause:Instruction Book defective(GET0698-002A / PT PADAMA)
Symgrup:Accesories
Modgrup:KD
oper:edit
id:4
```

How do I do to change `oper:` value?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correct you can use [prmNames](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) parameter of jqGrid. For example

```
prmNames: {oper:"myoper", editoper:"myedit"}
```

will change the `oper=edit` data send to the server to `myoper=myedit`.

Comment: in which place should I put that `prmNames`?

Comment: @nunu: I wrote that is is **parameter of jqGrid**. If you click on the link [prmNames](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) you will see all parameters like `url`, `datatype`, `mtype` and so on. You should just add an additional parameter to you jqGrid definition.